# How can I add FindAll filters at runtime?

Tags: c#, replace, types

I have a search decorator with something like this:

```
Records.FindAll(a => a.field == val)
```

each searcher narrows the `Records` in this manner.
I feel like this is slowing the server too much by getting so many records to begin with. What I really need it to do is something like this.

```
func<t,bool> exp1 = a => a.field1 == val1;
func<t, bool> exp2 = a=> a.field2 == val2;
Records.FindAll(exp1 && exp2);
```

I would need the `.FindAll()` to include a lambda from each Decorator Object.
Any thoughts?

Surely someone, somewhere has come up with a solution to the many searchable fields problem.

Comment: You'd be losing all static type safety by doing this.  You'd be effectively (if not actually) passing in the string value of the property, rather than a  C# method that would be statically verified to be type safe.

Comment: You need to dig into using expression trees to look at PropertyInfo instances to get static, non-string type info. If you're interested in that have a look at how something like AutoMapper does it.

Comment: Why would you *rather* post your alternative solution than do what you did at the start?  It's *more* work, not less.

Comment: You can try using the [LINQKit PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). You could build a lot of predicates and combine them with AND or OR condition.